Mid 1960-70s film about kid climbing mountain in Europe
Around the late 80's to early 90's I saw a movie either on the TV or VHS that looked like it was filmed ~20 years earlier because the color seemed saturated like the films of the 60's/70's.  
The basic plot was the boy's father died climbing this mountain, in Europe (Switzerland?), so the boy wanted to climb it.  He lived with his grandpa who reluctantly trained the kid. I remember during the training scenes the grandpa had the kid hike/run with a rucksack often.  The grandpa stressed the danger of the crux chimney. The grandpa also stressed the importance of training with an unbalanced pack because that is how it would be during the climb. 
At the end of the movie the kid succeeds in summiting the mountain right after climbing a chimney that was the crux of the climb.  There was very little, if any snow/ice on the route.
The film was in English, and I don't recall any distinctly non-American accents, so I believe it was an American film and/or American actors. The movie wasn't animated.

I think you may be looking for Walt Disney's Third Man on the Mountain.

Third Man on the Mountain is a 1959 American Walt Disney Productions film set during the golden age of alpinism about a young Swiss man who conquers the mountain that killed his father. It is based on Banner in the Sky, a James Ramsey Ullman novel about the first ascent of the Citadel, and was televised under this name. The movie inspired the Matterhorn Bobsleds attraction at Disneyland Park.

Here's a brief video of part of the film:




It sounds like "Banner in the sky", a novel by James Ullman which was turned into a movie in 1963 by Walt Disney. The story is the same, at least. It's hard to find, but here's the IMDB site. 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0560978/

The imdb page you linked shows that as a remake of the accepted answer
